# 2 метода сотировки через свитч с++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
const int n = 5;
int first, last;

void quicksort(int* mas, int first, int last)
{
    int mid, count;
    int f = first, l = last;
    mid = mas[(f + l) / 2]; 
    do
    {
        while (mas[f] < mid) f++;
        while (mas[l] > mid) l--;
        if (f <= l) 
        {
            count = mas[f];
            mas[f] = mas[l];
            mas[l] = count;
            f++;
            l--;
        }
    } while (f < l);
    if (first < l) quicksort(mas, first, l);
    if (f < last) quicksort(mas, f, last);
}
void main()
{
    setlocale(0, "Rus");
    int* A = new int[n];
    srand(time(NULL));
    cout << "Исходный массив: ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        A[i] = rand() % 10;
        cout << A[i] << " ";
    }
    int U;
    cout << "\n 1.Сортировка Хоара \n 2.Сортировка выбором" << endl;
    cin >> U;

    switch (U) {
    case'1':
        first = 0; last = n - 1;
        quicksort(A, first, last);
        cout << endl << "Итоговый массив: ";
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cout << A[i] << " ";
        delete[]A;

    case'2':
        for (int startIndex = 0; startIndex < n - 1; ++startIndex)
        {
            int smallestIndex = startIndex;

            for (int currentIndex = startIndex + 1; currentIndex < n; ++currentIndex)
            {
                if (A[currentIndex] < A[smallestIndex])
                    smallestIndex = currentIndex;
            }

            swap(A[startIndex], A[smallestIndex]);
        }

        for (int index = 0; index < n; ++index)
            cout << A[index] << ' ';

    }
    system("pause>>void");
}
```

При переходе на свитч, выполнение сортировки не происходит. Буду признателен, если подскажите, что я сделал не так. Заранее спасибо.

[image: Скриншот из консоли]

Answer (score 3):

Вы сравниваете число `int` c числовым кодом символа `'1'` (49). А еще пропущен `break;`. А еще для использования функции `rand` необходимо включать заголовочный файл `cstdlib`. А еще глобальные переменные с именами, совпадающими с локальными. А во втором случае массив не удаляете. Ну и сам алгоритм выглядит как-то подозрительно, там действительно должены быть перебор по одному элементу и рекурсия?